# How to add date in dd/MM/yyyy to mysql in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used an ajax calendarExtender tool and set Format to dd/MM/yyyy while inserting the date 21/12/2013 to mysql its giving error

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cnnstring);

string cmdText = "INSERT INTO trydate(Dob) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
conn.Open();
int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Label1.Text = "Data Saved";
TextBox1.Text = "";
```

please help me to overcome from this.

Comment: what error you're getting..!!

Comment: I'd start by using a parameterised query, not only will it help your system work out the datatypes it'll prevent SQL injection attacks!

Comment: i got error like this "Incorrect date value: '01/02/2014' for column 'Dob' at row 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
string strText=TextBox1.Text
string qryStr = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}", Convert.ToDateTime(strText));
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO trydate(Dob) VALUES ('" + qryStr + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert `TextBox1.Text` to a `DateTime` variable, and change your query to parameterized query to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to make sure that `conn` is closed after executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cnnstring))
{
    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO trydate(Dob) VALUES (@Dob)";

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", dob);
        conn.Open();
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "Data Saved";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this ,

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO trydate(Dob) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "')";
```